# PhpStorm use with Selenium - register file type

Tags: php, phpstorm

One of my files was "marked as text", with the icon changing. In reality this is a PHP file. I have tried going to `Help -> Find Action -> Mark As` to try to get it back to PHP highlighting but it doesn't work. I've deleted the `.idea` folder, tried to change different settings but nothing works.

What Am I missing? How can I get the PHP highlighting back?

Answer (score 1):

In the project tree view right-click the file and you can toggle between `Mark as Plain Text` and `Mark as PHP` from the context menu. This works as well via `Find Action` as long as the focus actually is on the file entry, but **not** when another file in the editor frame has the focus and the target file is only selected in the tree view since this action is based on focus. Ensure you have properly set the focus when attempting to perform this action.

Answer (score 1):

If the file was marked as plain text, there should be **Mark as PHP** in its right-click menu. If you can't see this action, this likely means that file name was added to **Text** file type patterns in **Settings | Editor | File Types**:

[image]

Removing file name from the list of registered patterns should help